# Custom StdValueInstantiator or post-instantiation logic in Jackson and Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jackson

I'm trying to do a project-wide custom instantiation solution which would work for incoming JSON requests in Spring Boot REST API.

The project consists of request classes which have properties that are wrappers around actual property type - similar to how Optional<?> works - and what I'm trying to achieve is to set every request's property to Optional.empty even if the particular field is not supplied in the request body that Jackson is parsing into the object of appropriate class.

Obviously, one method would be to declare default value of the property in class declaration, but I'm hoping to do a more generic solution that wouldn't require manual intervention.

Something along the lines of either replacing StdValueInstantiator by a similar custom one which would set all Optional<> properies (through reflection) to the desired default value, or alternatively piggyback onto the process after Instantiation through an empty constructor and before the steps of actually setting properties from the JSON to set property values to their desired defaults.

The idea is to always have the same default value (in the style of Optional.empty)

I couldn't find a way to add this behavior.